# How to move a field to other position in a OpenERP7 form view?

Tags: xml, forms, view, odoo, openerp-7

I made a form view in OpenERP7, which inherits from an existing form view.

I am trying to move some field to other position, only moving, because I need to preserve its functionality.

Easy example: let's suppose that the name of the field I want to move is `field_to_move`, and I want to move it just after the field called `above_field`. I tried the next code:

```
<xpath expr="/form//field[@name='field_to_move']" position="replace">
    <xpath expr="/form//field[@name='above_field']" position="after">
        <field name="field_to_move" on_change="onchange_type(field_to_move)" />
    </xpath>
</xpath>
```

The result is wrong, I am generating the new field in a wrong position (the same before the changes) and the old field is still visible, so it is duplicated.

Any idea? I tried several things but nothing. Thak you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work

1. Hide the current position of field.

   ```
   <field name="field_to_move" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
   </field>
   ```
2. Move to desire place using below code.

   ```
   <field name='above_field' position="after">
       <field name="field_to_move"/>
   </field>
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's right! Do you know whether is this the best way to do it or not?

Comment: Yes. this is good way. And we can use two `xpath` for example we want to place a filed in `inside page` with desire position, than we need to use two xpath like one is `<xpath expr="//page[@string='Page name']" position='inside>'` and second xpath for desire position like `<xpath expr="//field[@name='field_name']" position='after>' Hope you will get idea.